# What do the different ping statuses returned by VBS scripts mean?

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, ping, vbscript, wmic

I have a VBS Script that executes this code

```
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address = '" & Cell & "'"
```

Cell - is the Excel cell with the hostname

Some of my results are shown as

```
"Unknown host"
"Request timed out"
"Unknown host"
"Destination host unreachable"
```

What is the difference between these ping status?

Some items of note:

- All hosts are on a wired network. Some of the computers maybe switched off.
- I just want to know what these statuses mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these are all self explanatory

```
"Request timed out"
```

The SQL server connection timed out although a connection could have been made.

```
"Unknown host"
```

Doesn't understand the host name (incorrect format maybe).

```
"Destination host unreachable"
```

Cannot reach/connect to the host despite the host name appearing to be correct.

**As per your comment**

I can see why there is confusion between "request time out" and "destination host unreachable" and why they could relate to the same thing... If you can't connect to a host within a certain amount of time, both messages could suffice.

I guess you're thinking it's about the "connecting too" instead of "whilst connected too".

When you connect to a data source with a query, the connection remains open until you have your results. Usually, there is a threshold (a timeout). Suppose the timeout was 3 minutes and a large (or inefficient/faulty) query could exceed that time. This would result in the time out message.

Comment: Whats the real difference between Request Timed Out vs Destination host not reachable". I assumed they meant the same thing.

Comment: @softwareisfun updated answer

Comment: I am not running Database queries. The SQL like command is a WMIC to get the Ping status. Therefore there is no database server involved. But let me see if the answer you provided applies to WMIC